# My France visa application was not processed and documents were returned

Tags: visas, france, tourist-visas, vfs-global, chicago

I applied for tourist visa for France at VFS Chicago. All the documents and application form with my passport was returned back. They said the application couldn't be processed since there is one document missing. What I should do in this case? Does this mean it's rejected? There is no way to contact VFS directly.

Answer (score 9):

"The application couldn't be processed" means the application wasn't evaluated or ruled on. This is not a rejection.

You can apply again. If you do, make certain you include all the required documents.